# php variables comparison == vs ===

Tags: php

this is code:

```
$s = 0;
$d = "dd";

if ($s == $d) {
    var_dump($s);
    die(var_dump($d));
}
```

result is:

```
int 0

string 'dd' (length=2)
```

Please explain why.

why `($s == $d)` results as true?

Of course, if `===` is used it will results as false but why this situation requires `===`?
Shouldn't it be returned false in both situations?

Comment: Not sure why there are downvotes on this question. It *might* be simple if you know the answer, but is shows someone who is trying to understand their code and getting to the nitty-gritty of how the language works. +1 from me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `(int)$d` equals with `0` and `0=0`

you must use strict comparison `===` for different character tyes `(string)` with `(int)`

Your `$d` is automatically converted to `(int)` to have something to compare.

Comment: You really have your finger on the pulse tonight :) +1

Comment: Tonight, it's freakin' 12PM here:)

Comment: You should move to a place that is further up the timezone, it's after seven PM Friday night here. (Awww, that just made me realize that I am a really sad bugger - spending Friday night answering programming questions)

Answer (score 4):

When you compare a number to a string, the string is first type juggled into a number. In this case, `dd` ends up being juggled into `0` which means that it equates to true `(0==0)`.

When you change the code to:

```
 <?php 
 $s = 1;
 $d = "dd";
 if ($s == $d)
 {
    var_dump($s);
    die(var_dump($d));
 }
 ?>
```

You will find that it doesn't pass the `if` statement at all.

You can more details by reading up on [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) and [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

Comment: @MihaiIorga Yeah, but I made a grand entrance! *swings cape* !

Answer (score 2):

The string "dd" is converted to int, and thus 0.

Another example :

```
if ( "3kids" == 3 )
{
      return true;
}
```

And yes, this returns true because "3kids" is converted to 3.

=== does NOT auto convert the items to the same type.

Also : `0 == false` is correct, but `0 === false` is not.

See : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 2):

The string will try to parsed into a number, returns `0` if it is not in right number format.

Answer (score 2):

As seen in the php website : 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

```
var_dump(0 == "a"); // 0 == 0 -> true
```

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, `==` should be pronounce "Probably Equals".

When comparing with `==`, PHP will juggle the file-types to try and find a match.

A string with no numbers in it, is evaluated to `0` when evaluated as an int.

Therefore they're equals.